# How to auto-post math markup on my github repo's page(s)?

Tags: math, github, markdown

I'm not sure if this is possible, but this is what I'd like to do:

I'd like to create a [literate program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming), hosted on github, and have the resulting human-friendly literature automatically published on my github's project page.  By "automatically published," I mean that I can run a script on my local machine that ends with "git push origin master," and ends up with a published human-friendly, math-containing document on github.  I'm open to compromises on the procedure to get there, but the simpler, the better.

Many people don't know what literate programming is, so I'll summarize that.  It's a system where you write a single document that can be translated into either source code or a human-friendly document.  The purpose is to very clearly explain the algorithm, in English (or other natural language), and it is considered useful when users may be as interested in reading about your algorithm as they are in using it directly.  Some folks (like Donald Knuth) consider literate programming as a critical tool in building any complex piece of software.

One idea to do this would be to generate something like a README.md file as the output of the literate program, but I don't know of any math support in github's markdown formatting.  It looks like github's wikis might support some math, but I don't know how to make the wiki be generated from the code -- as in, I'd like to be able to do a `git push origin master` from my machine, and have the github wiki automatically updated.

(Also, to understand why math support is important: I'm coming from a world of always using TeX or LaTeX to write papers, and I'm interested in a general system that other authors used to LaTeX could also use.)

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wikis are backed by their own git repo, so you can push to it and have it automatically update.  That's a different repo than the main one though.  As far as I know that stuff is only supported in the wikis, not in the main repo markdown processor.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there any way to find out how I can support math in any of the markup languages?  I have been searching the docs, but in every case it looks like math support is an extension that github does not support by default.

Comment: The wiki editor help should give you the info you need for whichever markup language you've picked for that page: https://img.skitch.com/20110507-rq75yf2yc1taqpa8jtdme4w83u.jpg

Comment: I've just tried Tekkub's example and it seems to be no longer supported?